# why `ls -d .` does not list all dirs, as `ls -d */` does?

Tags: ls

Like it says in the heading, I don't get why the "correct" usage of `ls -d` should add `*/` in order for `ls` to find the directories in my current dir, where adding the trivial `.` isn't helpful

Comment: It's the *shell*, not `ls`, that's "finding" directories when you use `*/`

Answer (score 1):

The `-d` option lists directories themselves, not their content. If you issue the command `ls -d .` then it will list the argument, i.e. `.`, a.k.a. the current directory by its own, rather than listing the contents of the argument, i.e., the files in the current directory.

`.` represents the current directory. `*/` matches all directories existing in the current directory.

Try `ls -dl .` for a more interesting variation of the `ls -d .` command.

Comment: You can expand your answer by mentioning that the `*` character is "expanded" by the shell into a list of files or directories. Compare it with `ls "*/"`.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli yes, I could, but I do not want to turn this into a bash course. I already indicated that it "matches...".